# CNTK + Keras: AttributeError: 'Variable' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

Tags: keras, cntk

I'm running Keras with CNTK backend.
I'm using Python 3.5 GPU-1bit-SGD on Windows 10.

Followed the instruction as given here to install and test the set-up. And everything works!

However, when I run my own code, I get this error:

```
numBins = y_pred.get_shape().as_list()[1]
  File "C:\Users\abisw\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\cntkkeraspy35\lib\site-packages\cntk\ops\functions.py", line 480, in __getattr__
    return getattr(outputs[0], name)
  File "C:\Users\abisw\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\cntkkeraspy35\lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py", line 1125, in <lambda>
    __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, Variable, name)
  File "C:\Users\abisw\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\cntkkeraspy35\lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py", line 83, in _swig_getattr
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (class_type.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'Variable' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: That actually looks like a problem with your code. Please make a [MCVE] that reproduces this error. Also, what instructions did you follow for that installation?

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing keras code with tensorflow code, **get_shape** is a tensorflow grammar, not keras grammar. If you want the variable shape, you should write:

```
from keras import K
K.int_shape(y_pred)
```